# Count the occurrences of each character in a alpha-numeric column in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a alpha-numeric column in a DataFrame. I would like get the total count of each characters(0-9, A-Z) occurs in the entire column.

e.g.

```
Serial
03000395
A000458B
667BC345
```

Desired Output

```
Character     Counts
0             7
1             0
2             0
3             3
.
.
A             1
B             2
C             1
..
Z
```

Comment: `Serial` is inside the dataframe?

Comment: Yes, it is a column in a dataframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Counter to get this

```
from collections import Counter
Counter('03000395 A000458B 667BC345)
```

Output:

```
Counter({'0': 7,
         '3': 3,
         '9': 1,
         '5': 3,
         ' ': 2,
         'A': 1,
         '4': 2,
         '8': 1,
         'B': 2,
         '6': 2,
         '7': 1,
         'C': 1})
```

EDIT: After clarifying comments about this being in a dataframe you can do this:

```
pd.DataFrame(df.Serial.value_counts()).reset_index().rename({'index':'Character','Serial':'Count'})
```

EDIT2: After even further clarification, I think this is what you want

```
counts = dict(Counter(''.join(df.Serial)))
pd.DataFrame({"Character":counts.keys(), "Count":counts.values()})
```

Comment: 'Serial' is a column in a dataframe

Comment: How can get the output as 2 column(Character, Count) dataframe

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the code.  value_counts only outputs how many times the entire value appears in the columns. Your previous function counter is how i want. however how do i change the output from a dictionary to a dataframe. Basically input is a column in a data frame and the output is also datafram with 2 columns (Character and Count)

Comment: Do you want one other dataframe or one per row in the original dataframe?

Comment: @SureshSridharan Please see my latest edit